# android- How to handle database not found in adb shell

Tags: android, sqlite

Just i am creating the database in my app. Now i follow the following steps to see the database(for emulator case).

1. run the app.
2. C:[..path..]\android-sdk-windows\tools>adb devices

List of devices attached
emulator-5554 device

3.C:[..path..]\android-sdk-windows\tools>adb -s emulator-5554 shell

***Here i am getting database not found error.***

4.#

```
ls /data/data/com.sqlitedemo/databases: not found
```

How to handle this.please can anybody help me.

```
package com.sqlitedemo;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class sqlitedemo extends Activity {
    
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        db = openOrCreateDatabase("TestData.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a space between ls and the argument :

```
ls /data/data/com.sqlitedemo/databases
```

Comment: # sqlite3 /data/data/example.SQLiteTest/databases/TestData.db---->Here what is sqlite3?